# Php websites don't work after changin php version

Tags: php, apache2, localhost

I work with php in a Ubuntu 13.04 environment.
I've configured apache so that in my home directory I have a `public_html` directory where I keep all the websites I'm working on and I can access them with `localhost/~homedir/website`. Everything used to work fine, but some days ago I downgraded php to version 5.3 to try and solve a problem (which then I didn't) and then I came back to php 5.4.9. This happened some days ago and I don't remember if after all this I checked any of my websites. Anyway, today I tried accessing one and it didn't work. On the apache error.log file I have this:

```
File does not exist: /home/carlo/public_html/website/index.php/welcome
Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/carlo/public_html/website/index (None could be negotiated).
```

The `.htaccess` I usually use is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~carlo/website/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cache|captcha|fonts|forum|media|img|min|css|js|scripts|images|uploads|docs|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap|public|tools|assets|xd_receiver.htm)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

On a side note, phpmyadmin is working. I can access it with `localhost/phpmyadmin`. In `/etc/apache2/conf.d/apache.conf` I have this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/
</IfModule>
```

What I think is that downgrading and upgrading php some configuration file changed, but I don't know which one and what to do. Can you help me figuring it out? Shall I post some other info?

EDIT:

I think I've found out the problem.
Apparently, upgrading php the following instructions were reactivated:

```
# To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    php_admin_value engine Off
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

So, commenting them solved the issue (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

Add in `.htaccess` file and try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: with this it gives me an Internal Server Error and in the log it says `Options not allowed here`

Comment: anyway I always had the same `.htaccess` and it worked, so I think the problem should be somewhere else

Comment: I've found the problem. I edited the question with the solution