# Apache2 don't execute PHP 5.6 script after upgrade

Tags: php, linux, apache, upgrade

I've upgrade PHP 5.5 to 5.6. After this my Apache don't execute my PHP script.

With Iceweasel (Firefox) i have a blank page and with google chrome it's display the code source.

My code source:

```
<?php

    echo "test";
?>
```

I follow this intructions: [Upgraded PHP now apache won`t execute php files anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489542/upgraded-php-now-apache-wont-execute-php-files-anymore)

I've installed `libapache2-mod-php5`.

And i've edited this file: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` and I've commented these lines in this file:

```
# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#       php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

[Php websites don't work after changin php version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936440/php-websites-dont-work-after-changin-php-version?rq=1)

And of course I don't forget to restart Apache2.

My linux distribution is Kali.

Comment: What does "don't execute" mean? It returns the original source code? Are you using short PHP tags?

Comment: There's definitely something fishy going on. ;)

Comment: Please consider to post more information about the issue, with your question and the few information you gave, the answer is not answerable

Comment: Sorry for this! I've edited my post with more information. If this is not enough what information do you want? Thx for your help!

Comment: Did you enable the module? e.g. `a2enmod php5`?

Comment: (Incidentally, Iceweasel and other browsers will show you a blank page because they're interpreting everything from the `<` of `<?php` to the `>` of `?>` as an unknown HTML element. You'd get the same behaviour with `<wibble ...>`, for example. You should always view the page *source* in your browser, or use a tool like curl or wget, to diagnose this kind of problem.)

Comment: Thank you! you're resolve the problem! The module wasnt activate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you've installed the module and edited the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` file, but you also need to check that the module is actually enabled.

Its module loader file, `php5.load` should appear in the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` directory if it's enabled (it'll be a symbolic link to the file in `mods-available`). If it doesn't, you need to enable it with with `sudo a2enmod php5` (and restart apache with `service apache2 restart`.)